# how to append comma inbetween json file in cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress, writefile

my write file :
cy.writeFile("cypress/fixtures/xlsxData.json", Newdata , { flag: 'a+' })

Newdata -
let Newdata = { FirstName:F_jsonData[i][0], MiddleName:F_jsonData[i][1], LastName:F_jsonData[i][2] }

and xlsxdata.json will be:

```js
 [ {
  "FirstName": "ABC",
  "MiddleName": "K",
  "LastName": "edf"
}{
  "FirstName": "sss",
  "MiddleName": "g",
  "LastName": "efg"
} ]
```

How can I add comma between 2 objects in the json file?

Comment: Your question needs to be more clear and you need to add some more details like from where this `FirstName:F_jsonData[i][0]` is coming from. How it is stored intially and so on?

Comment: Why does that matter?

Comment: F_jsonData[i][0] - has the json data parsed from excel file. doing data driven testing with cypress automation

Answer (score 6):

It's a mistake to use `{flag:'a+'}`, that's only useful for text-like, for example logs, which take a stream of lines.

Instead, let javascript append the structure correctly (applies to any objects, not just this one).

```js
const filePath = 'cypress/fixtures/xlsxData.json'
cy.readFile(filePath).then(data => {
  data.push(Newdata)
  cy.writeFile(filePath, data)   // write back the expanded data
})
```

Comment: but why is it not accepting file path as its throwing error -  Expected ',' or ']' after array element in JSON at position 74

Comment: i have used {flag:a+} to append json objects which i am parsing from excel file. excel file having 3 rows and trying to parse and write to json file.

Comment: Yes, I put the the wrong variable in the `cy.writeFile()` - see the update, do that - but do not use `{flag:a+}` it's a mistake for this scenario.

Comment: this still does not work it says Unexpected end of JSON input" at readfile.

Comment: It works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

If you want a comma, there is nothing stopping you from writing a comma.

```js
const filePath = 'cypress/fixtures/xlsxData.json'
cy.writeFile(filePath, ', ', { flag: 'a+' })
cy.writeFile(filePath, Newdata , { flag: 'a+' })
```

Comment: hey it some what worked but thn even before ] i get comma:PFB: [ {
  "FirstName": "Deepika",
  "MiddleName": "K",
  "LastName": "bhat"
}, {
  "FirstName": "Diana",
  "MiddleName": "g",
  "LastName": "gomez"
},  ]                                                                                                                                                 only in between 2 json i should get, even if it is accepting coma at last, i will get error.

Comment: any idea how i can avoid last comma and get coma only inbetween the jsons